# Type specification in Python functions

Tags: python

I believe types can be specified in Python as is mentioned here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

I am using following simple function modified from one on above page:

```
def greeting(name: str) -> str:
    print("From inside function.")
    return 'Hello ' + name
```

As expected, it works when a string is sent as argument. However, when an integer is used as an argument, it still reaches inside the function and there is error thrown at `return` statement level:

```
> print(greeting(55))
From inside function.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(greeting(55))
  File "testing.py", line 13, in greeting
    return 'Hello ' + name
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Same error occurs if the function definition does not have type specification:

```
def greeting(name):
```

Then what is the advantage of having type specification in function header?

```
def greeting(name: str) -> str:
```

Comment: [***"Python will remain a dynamically typed language"***](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#non-goals) - those hints are for humans, and tools *other than* the interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is dynamically typed; at run time `name` can be *any* value. The function annotations only provide type *hints*, which Python itself ignores but other tools can use for *static* type checking.  That is, at runtime, `greeting(4)` is perfectly legal (but results in a run-time error when you try to evaluate `'Hello' + 4`). A tool like [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org), however, will flag `greeting(4)` as an error because `4` is, indeed, not the `str` that you said `name` *should* take.

Think of the type hints as parseable and machine-checkable comments.

[doc.python about type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)